# Error on socket.recv (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I got a small python program that communicates with an EV3 robot (lego's robot) via BT. The program sends the EV3 a number 1/2 or 3, the robot makes a predefined movement and send back 'A' to indicate that the movement is done and that it is ready for next command.

The system works great but once in a while the python app crushes with this error message: 
'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.' this comes from socket.recv that is called inside btListener() thread.

The relevant python parts:

```
    import bluetooth
    from gmail import *
    import re
    from gtts import gTTS
    from time import sleep
    import pygame
    import serial
    import thread
    import os
    import ftplib
    from StringIO import StringIO
    from blynkapi import Blynk

    def a():    #Send 'a' to 'Status' mailbox
        print "Send a to robot"
        for i in commandA:
            client_sock.send(chr(i))
        sleep(1)

    def b():    # Send 'b' to 'Status' mailbox


    def c():     # Send 'c' to 'Status' mailbox


    def clear():  # Send clear array to 'Status' mailbox
        for i in clearArray:
            client_sock.send(chr(i))

    def btListener():
        # Listen for end of run reply from the EV3
        global ev3Flag, listenFlag
        while True:
            if listenFlag and (not ev3Flag):
                    try:
                        data = client_sock.recv(1024)     #Check if EV3 is ready for new command
                        if data[-2] == 'A':
                            ev3Flag = True
                            print "Received 'Ready' from EV3  "
                            sleep(1)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        print "Failed to read data from socket"


    def queueHandler():
        # Read next command from QueueArray, call sendFunc and clear the queue
        global ev3Flag, listenFlag, queueArray
        while True:
            if len(queueArray) > 0 and ev3Flag:
                sendFunc(queueArray[0])
                queueArray.pop(0)


    def sendFunc(cmd):
        #Send the next command on QueueArray to the EV3
        global ev3Flag, listenFlag
        if cmd == 1:
            try:
                ev3Flag = False
                listenFlag = False
                a()
                listenFlag = True
                sleep(3)                
                clear()                 # clear the EV3 btsocket with a default message
            except Exception as e:
                print "Error on sendFunc cmd = 1"
                print(e)

        elif cmd == 2:
            try:
            except Exception as e:

        elif cmd == 3:
            try:
            except Exception as e:


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        # Blynk setup
        blynk = Blynk(auth_token)
        switch1 = Blynk(auth_token, pin = "V0")
        switch2 = Blynk(auth_token, pin = "V1")
        switch3 = Blynk(auth_token, pin = "V2")
        print "Blynk connected"

        queueArray = []  # Queue array to hold incoming commands
        listenFlag = True  # Listen to message from EV3
        ev3Flag = True  # EV3 ready for new command flag

        # BT CONNECTION WITH EV3 #
        print "Searching for BT connections: "

        nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()

        for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
            print bdaddr + "  -  " + bluetooth.lookup_name(bdaddr)
            if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name(bdaddr):
                target_address = bdaddr
                break

        server_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)

        port = 1
        server_sock.bind(("", port))
        server_sock.listen(1)

        client_sock, address = server_sock.accept()
        print "Accepted connection from ", address

        if target_address is not None:
            print "found target bluetooth device with address ", target_address
        else:
            print "could not find target bluetooth device nearby"
        # END BT CONNECTION WITH EV3 #

        try:
            thread.start_new_thread(queueHandler, ())
        except Exception as e: print(e)

        try:
              thread.start_new_thread(btListener, ())
        except Exception as e: print(e)


    while True:
        res1 = switch1.get_val()
        res2 = switch2.get_val()
        res3 = switch3.get_val()

        if (int)(res1[0]) == 1:
            print "Add 1 to queue"
            queueArray.append(1)

        if (int)(res2[0]) == 1:
            print "Add 2 to queue"
            queueArray.append(2)

        if (int)(res3[0]) == 1:
            print "Add 3 to queue"
            queueArray.append(3)
```

**Edit 1:**

I tested it a bit more and it seems that the crush happens when the program tries to recv data and send data the same time. (via the clear() or a()/b()/c() functions), could that be the situation?
I'm new to sockets so the first solution that comes in mind is create a flag to limit the action of the socket, is there a better/smarter way to keep that from happening?

**Edit 2:**

I moved the 'listenFlag = True' line inside sendFunc() to after my call to clear() and it seems to solve the problem which was probably due to the python program trying to receive and sand at the same time.

Comment: The error message means that the error is with the host, not your script. Have you checked to make sure that when the error occurs the robot is still on or didn't just randomly lose connection?

Comment: The BT connection went off for any reason (timeout, too much noise, incorrect packet received on one side, etc.) and you are trying to read from a closed socket.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin the robot is still running as it should.

Comment: @SergeBallesta is there a way to identify what cause the socket to close?
Also I edited my questions thinking I found the reason for the error, could you comment on that please?

Comment: I think that I solved the problem (see edited parts). 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the 'listenFlag = True' line inside sendFunc() to after my call to clear() and it seems to solve the problem which was probably due to the python program trying to receive and sand at the same time.